# Best practice to handle many data from cloud database into Listview?

Tags: php, android, listview, android-listview

I would like to ask for suggestions or for the best practice on **how to handle a lot of data that is loaded from database(cloud/php scripts) to the android listview**. I don't have any idea on how to deal with this matter.

**To elaborate the scenario:** lets say i have a database of list of students in a first year level. Let's say a hundred of them. In my current method, I just query all of them (showing the progressdialog) and wait until the data is all downloaded and displayed it in the listview(closing the progressdialog). I know this not the best way to do it since you need to consider bigger data.

I tried to download and test this: https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/source/checkout  from google team but still i don't get the bigger picture since in the example the data is all static.

What I want to do is:

- while downloading the data from server, a little progressbar will appear in the header of the list view and once finished it will disappear.
- Let's say i have 100 data results, but in my listview I want to display the top 10 and once scrolled down adding another 10 and so-on.

**I just want to know the proper implementation or handling of large data in listview for android.**

I would really really appreciate all your suggestions and comments with my problem.

Thanks Chkm8,

Comment: If you have any idea on PHP or you have any friend who's working on it, they can design a web-service for you from where you can get 10-10 data based on your request. You can use lazy loader or load more button on your screen with listview and update your listview on press of data. There're so many examples on internet. If you want I can shre with you.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/ and http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-listview-endless-adapter.html and http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699&seqNum=4 and  and https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless
 lots more on Google/Bing/Yahoo

Comment: yes, if you could share it. ill' really appreciate it. But is it a good way to do to limit your query by 10. and once the listview is scrolled down you will call another query of the next 10?. so for data of 100 you would request 10 times.

Comment: Exactly.. and above are some links.

Comment: thanks, sUndeep for this help., ill work on it., (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the new Volley API issued late last year to implement this. A great example which can help you implement this is the following [tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Thanks @Michele La Ferla, I had used volley in my one project but know i'm looking on retrofit as well.

Comment: Have you tried using this tutorial? it might help you - http://square.github.io/dagger/

Comment: No, I havent tried it yet but its on my list. As of now, my priority is to learn how to use retrofit. Btw, have you tried retrofit? Im having hard time on how to implement the caching. I've incorporated okhttp but could not get to it. Hope you could give some tips.

Comment: I have never worked with Retrofit actually, but I will see what I can do to help you.

Comment: You can try the following links: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518. If you used volley before, this would be a great article http://captechconsulting.com/blog/clinton-teegarden/volley-vs-retrofit-battle-royale-0 or this http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/